# Simulate impulsive signal and plotting

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

I'm trying to plot an impulsive signal (Taken from a scientific paper), the equation of the impulsive signal is:
[image: Impact formula]

where:

Ar= Amplitude of the impulses and equals 1.5

fm= fault characteristic freq. equals to 50 Hz

f=resonant frequency equals to 2000 Hz

F=sampling freq. equals to 10 kHz

betha= decay parameter equals 500}

total of 20.000 samples are simulated for the signal

the corresponding plot of the simulated signal should look like:
[image]

what I did is is:

```
#Constants:
A_r=1.5
f=2000
r=-0.01
F=10**3
f_m=50
b=500
y_plt=[]

def y(k):
    return A_r*np.sin(2*pi*f*(k-r*F/f_m)/F)*np.exp(-b*(k-r*F/f_m))/F
x=np.linspace(0,0.2,20000)
for i in x:
    y_plt.append(y(i))

fig=plt.figure(1)
ax=plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y_plt)
```

getting the next plot:

[image]plt.show()

(Which is not similar to the plot needed)
So my question is if everyone knows what I'm doing wrong, also the r parameter is not given.

--EDIT--

```
#Constants:
A_r=1.5
f=2000
r0=2
F=10**4
f_m=50
b=500
y_plt=[]
y_sum=[]

def y(k,r):
    t=(k- r*F/f_m)/F
    return A_r*np.sin(2*pi*f*t)*np.exp(-b*t)

for j in np.linspace(0,20000,20000,endpoint=False):   #k
    for i in np.linspace(0,r0,r0,endpoint=False):   #r
        y_sum.append(y(j,i))
        pene=np.sum(y_sum)
    y_plt.append(pene)
    
plt.figure(1)        
plt.plot(np.linspace(0,20000,20000,endpoint=False),y_plt)
plt.show()
```

Now, what I can't figure out is how to make it an periodic signal. I think it has relation to the r factor, but if I change it doesn't change the plot at all.

[image: Simple Impulse]

Answer (score 2):

## 1.

> F=sampling freq. equals to 10 kHz

But you wrote

```
F = 10 ** 3
```

In Python `**` mean exponentiation, so this is just 10<sup>3</sup> = 1000. That is, you have used F = 1 kHz in your code.

If you want to express 10.0 × 10<sup>3</sup>, use:

```
F = 10e3
#     ^
```

## 2.

```
A_r * np.sin(2*pi*f*(k-r*F/f_m)/F) * np.exp(-b*(k-r*F/f_m))/F
#                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Compared with your equation

> [image]

Note that the `/ F` part should be *inside* the `np.exp`, but you have put it outside.

There are so many parenthesis in the same line which mistakes can easily happen. You should better factor out the intermediate variable to make it easier to read:

```
def y(k):
    t = (k - r*F/f_m) / F
    return A_r * np.sin(2*pi*f*t) * np.exp(-b*t)
```

## 3.

Note that your equation has a ∑<sub>r</sub> — it is a summation of waves over many *r*. Are you sure A_r is just a single value?

Comment: I made the corrections, thank you for your good eye. Ar is a constant, equals to 1.5. i didnt consider the sum (Very good point). How can i add this sum. as part of the function?

Comment: @tomzko: Use a for loop, like `total = 0 ↵ for r in ......: ↵ total += ......`. But you need to know the valid range of *r*.